# cmake set_source_files_properties not working properly

Tags: cmake

I have a project that has a bunch of .c files that need to be compiled as C files, but I need one of them to be compiled as C++ code.
I tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690800/can-cmake-use-g-to-compile-c-files) but it did not work as expected. Instead of making only filename.c be compiled as C++, it compiles all the files in my project as C++ code. Without that call, all files are compiled as C.

I even tried this:

```
set_source_files_properties(${FILES_SRC} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE C)
set_source_files_properties(filename.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)
```

Where the `FILES_SRC` variable holds all my source files.

I am using CMake 2.8.12 and the Visual Studio 11 ARM generator.

Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up compiling the library using the C compiler and added the C++ code in a separate library for which I created a C interface so it can be called from my C library.