# How to make CLion to recognize .c files as c++ (and not as plain c)

Tags: c++, c, ide, clion

By default CLion C and C++ files has united file type in Settings->Editor->File Types
But in inspect code .c file recognize as plain C (for example type bool requires the inclusion < stdbool.h >) but actually it must be compiled as C++

Help->About:
CLion CL-140.2310.6
Build #CL-140.2310, built on February 12, 2015
...

Comment: Are you really using a lowercase `.c` extension for C++ source code?  Or it really is C code, but you want to run it through the more comprehensive C++ type checker?

Comment: Yes, lowercase .c extension is a heavy heritage of more than a decade of project which now contain C++ code.

Comment: There is a standard associating some extensions with specific languages. Forcing tools to ignore this standards will create lots of problems, spatially for future maintainer. It is easier and safer to just rename those files.

Answer (score 3):

### for CMakeLists.txt project (without clangd completion)

Put

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${SOURCE_FILES} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)
```

in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205822539/comments/205713325
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/LANGUAGE.html

As commented by user7610 below this seems not to work when clangd completion is enabled (though I haven't confirmed it yet).

### for compilation database project

insert `""-xc++","` to `[].arguments[1]` in `compile_commands.json`.

```
--- compile_commands_original.json  2022-03-10 12:08:05.025572787 +0900
+++ compile_commands.json   2022-03-10 12:09:16.250045217 +0900
@@ -12663,6 +12663,7 @@
     {
         "arguments": [
             "g++",
+            "-xc++",
             "-c",
             "-std=c++11",
             "-fno-PIE",
```

(This happens when I build gcc with bear.)

Comment: Wow this is great. That should be the answer lol

Comment: This no longer works with the Clangd autocompletion enabled. I had to go to Settings in `Languages & Frameworks` -> `C/C++` -> `Clangd` and `Disable Clangd completion`. Only then the autocompletion appeared for me.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the .c files to a proper suffix for C++, for example .cpp:

```
for i in `find . -name '*.c'`; do j=`echo $i | sed s/\.c/\.cpp/` ; mv $i $j; done
```

Seriously, if it is C++ code, it doesn't make sense to have it in .c files.

Once you have a working CMakeLists.txt, there is no reason to preserve the .c extension, since you can use cmake to generate build configuration for almost any build system on earth :-) See the cmake documentation for "generators":  http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-generators.7.html

Comment: Of course, changing file extensions, this is the first that comes to mind, however, it will lead to changes in the build system project (by the way, we don't use cmake; CMakeLists.txt generate himself CLion) and in order to try a new IDE would not like to change the project. I.e., my question was whether in the CLion fine-tune the type of the source file. Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: @AlexeyNikitin: sure, I understand. What I wanted to suggest is too look at cmake generators, and then make the bold move to convert your build system to cmake :-) You will be happy, I assure you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Clangd autocompletion engine in CLion, and with that, the recursive `set_source_files_properties` CMake command (from [Can CMake use g++ to compile C files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690800/can-cmake-use-g-to-compile-c-files/71172586#71172586)) did not work.

To fix it, I added file `.clangd` to the root of my project, containing

```yaml
CompileFlags:                        # Tweak the parse settings
  Add: [-xc++, -std=c++20]           # treat all files as C++
  Compiler: clang++                  # Change argv[0] of compile flags to `clang++`
```

The config file is documented at https://clangd.llvm.org/config.

Comment: I had to revisit this and it seems that the clangd in Clion ignores that config file now? /me confused...