# The "-x c++" flag for g++ under MinGW64 causes "stray [...] in program" error

Tags: cmake, g++, mingw, linker-errors, clion

Minimal reproducible example:

1. In CLion, using the MinGW toolchain (version `w64 6.0`, with `g++ 8.1.0`), create a new project with the "C++ executable" template
2. Write the following in `CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
   project(codeforces)

   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -x c++")

   add_executable(codeforces main.cpp)
   ```
3. Write the following program in `main.cpp`:

   ```cpp
   int main() { return 0; }
   ```
4. Build the project with the default configuration

At the linking stage, I get a bunch of `stray [...] in program` errors:

```
CMakeFiles\codeforces.dir/objects.a:2:59: error: stray '`' in program
 /               1598178122  0     0     0       14        `
[...]
```

But, if I remove the `-x c++` flag, I don't get this error anymore, and everything builds fine. Why is this?

Comment: Why do you ever need `-x c++` option? Isn't a compiler automatically interprets `.cpp` as C++ source file? If you want to compile `.c` as C++, then see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690800/can-cmake-use-g-to-compile-c-files).

Comment: @Tsyvarev True, I don't need it at a practical level; but still it shouldn't produce an error, it's just redundant in that case. (And it would be needed if I was using a non-standard file extension.)

Comment: "And it would be needed if I was using a non-standard file extension." - Non standard file extensions should still be recognized by CMake. Otherwise they won't be compiled irrespective to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. As for particular error you got, try to examine **exact** command lines used for compiling and linking. While these command lines are produced by CMake, it expects `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to contain "global" flags, which affect on the whole produced command line. But `-x`  flag could affect only on a part of the command line, if that command line contains, e.g, `-c` flag.