# How to compile a c file with Qt and CMake?

Tags: qt, cmake

With **Qt5.15.1** and cmake.

Starting from a new blank qml project generated by qtCreator. I need to add a c file.

In  CMakeLists.txt, I added the file like this:

```
  add_executable(untitled1
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
    c_file.c
  )
```

If I do a full build, here's the log file:

```
[ 20%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target untitled1
[ 20%] Built target untitled1_autogen
Scanning dependencies of target untitled1
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/untitled1_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/main.cpp.obj
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/mainwindow.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled1.exe
[100%] Built target untitled1
```

As you can see, the c file is not compiled. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7693134/2674506 ?

Comment: pff! I did tenth of google searches and did not find it... Thanks. That's perfect.