# How can I have CMake compile the same input file in two different languages?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, build, cross-language

I have a file named `foo.bar`. I want to compile it once as a C++ file, into a `mycpplib` library target, and once as a C file, into a `myclib` target; and I want to do it in the same build, with the same `CMakeLists.txt`.

Now, I know I can arbitrarily set a source file's associated language, like so:

```
set_source_files_properties(foo.bar PROPERTIES LANGUAGE C)
```

but this doesn't look like it'll help in my case. Is there something I can do at the CMake level?

Notes:

- Related question: [The single-arbitrary-language case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7690800/1593077).
- There are non-CMake solutions to this, e.g. duplicating the file; using a symlink with a different name; having a file with `#include "otherfile"` as its contents etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create library targets `mycpplib` and `myclib` in the **different directories** (in the different `CMakeLists.txt`). That way you may call `set_source_files_properties` in the directory where `mycpplib` library is created, and that call won't affect on `myclib`.

There are also DIRECTORY and TARGET_DIRECTORY options for command [set_source_files_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_source_files_properties.html), which could affect on the directory where the property will be visible:

```
# In 'c/CMakeLists.txt`
# add_library(myclib ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.bar)
```

```
# In 'cpp/CMakeLists.txt`
# add_library(mycpplib ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.bar)
```

```
# In CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(c)
add_subdirectory(cpp)
set_source_file_properties(foo.bar TARGET_DIRECTORY myclib
  PROPERTIES LANGUAGE C)
set_source_file_properties(foo.bar TARGET_DIRECTORY mycpplib
  PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)
```

Comment: It's weird that you can't set this property per target, period.

Comment: As far as I understand, CMake has a **per-target** properties and **per-file** properties. But it lacks for "per-file-per-target" properties. Options `DIRECTORY` and `TARGET_DIRECTORY` for the `set_source_file_properties` are just helpers, they don't introduce additional concepts.